# Why output parameter will not change outside of function

Tags: c, struct

### Background

I wrote a function named `removeIllegalMoveFromMovesCell` to remove data from some variables, let's call it x and y for now.
The value of x **does change** inside the function but will not update outside of the function.

**Calling the method:**

```
removeIllegalMoveFromMovesCell(movesArr[row][col].moves,&(movesArr[row][col].size), row, col);
```

---

**Explaining the variables**

x and y variables that was mentioned above are `movesArr[row][col].moves` and `movesArr[row][col].size`, they are based on those structs:

```
typedef struct _move {
    char rows;
    char cols;
} move;

typedef struct _movesArray {
   unsigned int size;
   move* moves;
} movesArray;
```

And here is how I create them:

```
movesArray* arr = (movesArray*)malloc(sizeof(movesArray));

move* movesArr1 = (move*)malloc(2 * sizeof(move));
move* movesArr2 = (move*)malloc(2 * sizeof(move));

move move1, move2, move3, move4;

move1.rows = -2;
move1.cols = 3;

move2.rows = 1;
move2.cols = 3;

move3.rows = -2;
move3.cols = 5;

move4.rows = 1;
move4.cols = 2;

movesArr1[0] = move1;
movesArr1[1] = move2;

movesArr2[0] = move3;
movesArr2[1] = move4;

arr[0].size = 2;
arr[1].size = 2;

arr[0].moves = movesArr1;
arr[1].moves = movesArr2;
```

---

**`removeIllegalMoveFromMovesCell` method:**

```
void removeIllegalMoveFromMovesCell(move* moves, int* size, int currRow, int currCol) {
int i;
int cloneIndex = 0;

move* movesClone = (move*)malloc((*size - 1) * sizeof(move));

for (i = 0; i < *size; i++) {
    if (!isMoveOutOfBounds(currRow, currCol,
        getPureNumber(moves[i].rows), getPureNumber(moves[i].cols))) {

        movesClone[cloneIndex].rows = moves[i].rows;
        movesClone[cloneIndex].cols = moves[i].cols;
        cloneIndex++;
    }
}

moves = (move*)realloc(moves, cloneIndex * sizeof(move));

for (i = 0; i < cloneIndex; i++) {
    moves[i] = movesClone[i];
}

*size = cloneIndex;

}
```

---

### The Problem and what I have tried so far:

While `size` variable changes outside of the method (And by that changing `movesArr[row][col].size`),  `moves` variable receive all of `movesClone` variable inside the method and will change its value inside the method but won't change outside of it (`movesArr[row][col].moves`).

**`move` is acting as a local variable although I passed his reference and not its value, I cannot understand why it won't change outside of the method**

---

### Extra info:

Here is `getPureNumber` function that is used inside `removeIllegalMoveFromMovesCell`

```
int getPureNumber(char c) {//simple return `movesArr[row][col].size` as number
if (c < 0)
    return c - 0;
return c;
}
```

Comment: `moves` **is** a local variable within the function. In C all parameters are passed by value. You only modify the local copy of `moves`. There must be some dupes around....

Comment: Side note: While you won't notice any change in `moves` outside that function, the memory where it points to **is** affected by your `realloc` call. You might end up with a pointer to invalid memory

Comment: @Gerhardh, thx for the comment, but actually I had a version of the function where I received move as `move** moves` and it did not worked. I will look at your linkes and try to find out what I did wrong.